# term/w32-win.el could not be found

Tags: windows, emacs, windows-installer

I just downloaded emacs and I try to run `runemacs.exe` and I get the message:

> The Emacs Windows installation file "term/win32-win.el" could not be found in your Emacs installation. Emacs checked the following directories for the file:
>
> ```
> ("c:\emacs\site-lisp", "c:\emacs\lisp", "c:\emacs\leim")
> ```

Some places that people have said to download the fullbin file but I don't know where to find that one? The one I downloaded was a barebin and I couldn't find any fullbins on the site where it came from.

Any ideas?

Comment: `emacs-24.3-bin-i386.zip`:  http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/windows/

Comment: I wouldn't think that such an important file would be in the fullbin only. Have you looked around for it? Do you have a `term` directory somewhere?

Comment: @lawlist Thank you. That's the one.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by downloading the file [@lawlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477512/term-w32-win-el-could-not-be-found?noredirect=1#comment39762463_25477512) pointed to in his comment. Now everything is running normally.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the "share" folder does not get extracted out of the zip with "Extract all".  You need to manually extract the "share" folder out and place it as a sibling to "bin".

Answer (score 0):

I solved it somehow.

Extract your zip file in your root.In `C:\` for example.

It should be some pathing bug, it didnt worked in my downloads folder but worked in root.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with running `addpm.exe` found in `emacs\bin`.

GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2019-08-29